# Routing Error with Edit (Rails 3.2)

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, routes, edit

I'm making items and they belong to a specific user. I was making my differend actions and everything works (items get made with right user id, image upload and so on).

Now for the edit action everything is oke, the page gets rendered, current item information is filled in. If I then click on the "update" button I get a routing error. (No route matches [POST] "/items/6")

My Controller items_controller.rb

```
# items_controller.rb
#-------------------  
class ItemsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :signed_in_user
  respond_to :html, :js

  def edit
   @item = current_user.items.find(params[:id])
   @categorys = current_user.items.group(:category)
  end

  def update
    if @item.update_attributes(params[:item])
       redirect_to items_path
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end
end
```

The @item variable gets the current item form the ID, then also the @categorys will display already used categorys where the user can pick from.

Now my **edit.html.erb file** (its very long im using bootstrap)

```
<%= provide(:title, 'Edit Item') %>
<h1>Edit Item</h1>
<div class="row">
  <div class="span7">
    <%= form_for(@item, html: {class: "form-vertical"}) do |f| %>
        <fieldset>
          <span class="legend">Please pick a logo that represents the item.</span>
          <%= render 'error_messages' %>
          <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="name">1. Give your item a name. Please don't include the volume of the
              item.</label>

            <div class="controls">
              <%= f.text_field :name, size: nil, class: 'input-xlarge', id: 'name' %>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="logo">2. Select a Logo for the item (this will help identifying the
              item)</label>

            <div class="controls">
              <%= image_tag @item.logo.url(:original), alt: @item.name %>
              <%= f.file_field :logo, size: nil, id: 'logo', 'accept' => 'image/*' %>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="category">3. Type the name of a new category or click on an
              existing</label>
            <ul class="breadcrumb category-select">
              <% @categorys.each do |c| %>
                  <li><a href="#"><%= c.category %></a></li>
              <% end %>
            </ul>
            <div class="controls">
              <%= f.text_field :category, size: nil, class: 'input-xlarge', id: 'category' %>
            </div>
          </div>


          <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label">4.Specify how much 1 quantity is and how many items you have in stock at this
              moment.<strong>Don't use this for updating the stock, please go to stock!</strong><br>
              For example: a bottle of coke 0.25l and I have 24 of them.</label>

            <div class="form-horizontal category-stock">
              <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="quantity">Quantity (l)</label>

                <div class="controls">
                  <div class="input-append">
                    <input class="span1" id="quantity" name="quantity" type="text">
                    <span class="add-on">l</span>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="amount">Amount (#)</label>

                <div class="controls">
                  <div class="input-append">
                    <input class="span1" id="amount" name="amount" type="text">
                    <span class="add-on">#</span>
                  </div>
                </div>

              </div>
            </div>

            <%= f.text_field :stock, size: nil, type: 'hidden' %>

            <div class="form-actions category-stock">
              <%= f.submit "Edit Item", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
            </div>
          </div>

        </fieldset>


    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

My routes.rb file

```
root to: 'sessions#new'

  resources :items do
    member do
      get :category
    end
  end
  resources :events

  resources :ei_relationships, only: [:create, :destroy]

  resources :users
  resources :sessions, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]

  match '/signup', to: 'users#new'
  match '/signout', to: 'sessions#destroy', via: :delete
```

The log I get in my server:

```
Started GET "/items/6/edit" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-04-20 00:34:34 +0200
Processing by ItemsController#edit as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"6"}
  User Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."remember_token" = '5le_BlKtwTQWeS15pzlCGQ' LIMIT 1
  Item Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "items".* FROM "items" WHERE "items"."user_id" = 1 AND "items"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", "6"]]
  Rendered shared/_error_messages.html.erb (0.0ms)
  Item Load (1.0ms)  SELECT "items".* FROM "items" WHERE "items"."user_id" = 1 GROUP BY category
  Rendered items/edit.html.erb within layouts/application (8.0ms)
  Rendered layouts/_shim.html.erb (0.0ms)
  Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (1.0ms)
  Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (1.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 77ms (Views: 73.0ms | ActiveRecord: 1.0ms)


Started POST "/items/6" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-04-20 00:34:47 +0200

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [POST] "/items/6"):
  actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
  railties (3.2.3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call_app'
  railties (3.2.3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  activesupport (3.2.3) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:62:in `call'
  railties (3.2.3) lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
  railties (3.2.3) lib/rails/application.rb:220:in `call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
  railties (3.2.3) lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:14:in `call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:59:in `service'
  C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
  C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
  C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:191:in `block in start_thread'


  Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/routing_error.erb within rescues/layout (1.0ms)
```

And I think that are all the files. Like I said everything works but only the edit function seems to be broken when the edit button is pressed.

Thanks!

---

## EDIT

Allright after some digging I found the problem. I use jquery to update a hidden input that is a multiplication of 2 input fields. The code is below. Really dont understand why this code messes up rails routing..

```
// Calculate the stock from the 2 fields and insert it in the hidden field
        $('.category-stock').find('input').on("click select change", function () {
            $.calculateStock();
        });
        $.calculateStock = function () {
            var quantity = parseFloat($('input[name="quantity"]').val());
            var amount = parseFloat($('input[name="amount"]').val());

            var result = quantity * amount;
            if (isNaN(result)) {
                result = 0;
            }

            $('input[type="hidden"]').val(result);
        };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't see your update button markup, but it sounds as though you are trying to update by sending a post.  Your ItemsController#update action doesn't respond to post, it responds to put.

So the form_for associated with your update button needs to look something like this:

```
<%= form_for(@item, html: {class: "form-vertical", method: "put"}) do |f| %>
```

Comment: but normally doesnt rails do this stuff automatically? Like doesn't it know from the form_for that the item already is there so I mean to update it instead of making a new one? The button is in the template file on the bottom ( <%= f.submit "Edit Item", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>) I also have a user model that can be created and edited, on the edit form of this user I didn't need this line... why now? Thanks for your reply :)

Comment: Edit: tryed your solution, and it didnt work, same error now. (added the method: "put" inside the html: and outside, no difference). Any Idea?

Comment: Let's see your view code that has the update button.  Let's also see the rails console output, from the form submission request up to and including the error.

Comment: The view with the update button is "edit.html.erb" its in bold now in the question, I also updated the log from the server: the current version is hosted on github, here is the link https://github.com/JanStevens/bap-terminal thanks!

Comment: Found the problem my selector in Jquery changes EVERY hidden input, even the rails one, thats why! Thanks for your time!

Comment: Congrats for figuring it out.  And you're right -- Rails is smart enough to tell the difference without an explicit put.  If @item.new_record? is true, Rails should issue a post, otherwise Rails should issue a put.